# React Router won't render pushed page after first navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React web app and I'm trying to use [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to navigate between screens.

This is the route configuration in the App component:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <MainScreen />
          </Route>

          <Router path="/about">
            <About  />
          </Router>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  };
```

Somewhere in `MainScreen` I navigate to the About component, and it works:

```
this.props.history.push("/about");
```

But when I try to navigate back to `MainScreen` from the `About` page by pushing "/", it changes the URL in the browser, but does not render `MainScreen` (I keep seeing the `About` page).

I'm using `withRouter()` when exporting both `MainScreen` and `About`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have more than one `Router`, where once you navigate to the inner-`Router`, there is no home Route for `"/"` defined in it, so there's no component to render. The `Routers` only communicate within their own scope in a top-down like pattern. In the grand scheme of things, you really only need one `Router` for your entire application so that all defined `Routes` can effectively communicate with each other.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainScreen}>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  };
```